# How do I return an array instead of a FirebaseListObservable

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular2-services, ng2-charts

I have `ng2-charts` working on my Angular-cli built application.  I'm pretty new, so any help is appreciated.  I have data setup on Firebase.  I create a method in a service to access that data and when I use this code

```
getGraphData():Observable<any>{
        var graphData$ = this.af.database.list(`graphdata/${this.uid}`)
          .map(tspa => tspa.map(tpa => tpa.$value))
          .do(console.log);

        graphData$.subscribe();
        return Observable.of([]);
 }
```

the console logs the correct data.

ex. `[1000, 5000, 2000]`

the problem is when I change the method to return the result like so:

```
getGraphData():Observable<any>{
        return this.af.database.list(`graphdata/${this.uid}`)
          .map(tspa => tspa.map(tpa => tpa.$value))
}
```

and try to assign it to a variable in a component. I always get the console log of:

```
>FirebaseListObservable
```

I've seen different methods for getting my desired result such as using `flatMap` and `Observable.combineLatest()`  but I can't get any other result.  I've got json data that I want to assign to a variable as an array in order to display it in my bar chart.

graph.ts

```
  data$: any;
  form$: any;

  public barChartLabels:string[] = ['Account1', 'Account2', 'Account3', 'Account4', 'Account5', 'Account6', 'Account7'];
  public barChartType:string = 'bar';
  public barChartLegend:boolean = true;

  firstVar:any = [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90];
  secondVar:any = [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90];

  public barChartData:any[] = [
    {data: this.firstVar, label: 'Series A'},
    {data: this.secondVar, label: 'Series B'}
  ];
```

i would like to assign `firstVar` the new Firebase data. Any suggestions?

i usually access the method like this:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.firstVar = this.transactionsS.getGraphData();
    console.log(this.firstVar)

  }

updateGraph(){
   this.firstVar = this.transactionsS.getGraphData()
    console.log(this.firstVar)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not correctly using the Observables, remember it's asychronous.

*A brief note on Observables:*
"RxJS is a library for composing asynchronous and event-based programs by using observable sequences."
Observables are based on [Observer/Subscriber pattern](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#observerpatternjavascript). Basically, *don't think in terms of data, think in terms of events*.
When you use this return `this.af.database.list('graphdata/${this.uid}')`, an observable is created which waits for the event thats says asynchronous call is done (i.e. data collected or error).
`observers` or the term used in rxjs -`subscribers` must register iwth the obserbale to tell it that wwe are interested in your events, if some data comes along pls pass it to us. An observable can have multiple subscribers.
In your case there is no need to use flatmap, just pass the array as it is and set `subscriber(val => this.firstVar=val)`.

```
getGraphData():Observable<any>{
  // create observable and add map operator for data to be sent to subscriber 
   return this.af.database.list(`graphdata/${this.uid}`)
          .map(tspa => tspa.map(tpa => tpa.$value));
}


firstVar:string[] = []; 
ngOnInit() {
    // use subscribe to capture published data
    this.transactionsS.getGraphData().subscribe((val)=> this.firstVar=val);
    console.log(this.firstVar); // this will not work 

  }

updateGraph(){
   this.transactionsS.getGraphData().subscribe((val) => this.firstVar=val);

}
```

rxjs have good documentation, check it [here](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#observable)

Comment: Thank you. I need to learn still I will read the docs. I noticed with your solution I am not getting the desired result, but at least I'm a lot closer.  I had to add `.flatMap(list => list)` to the end of `getGraphData()` method in order to get an array with the data I desire.  One problem that may be unrelated, Does `flatMap` typically duplicate the data?  Instead of an array of `[1000, 1000, 5000]` i am getting `[1000, 1000, 5000, 1000, 1000, 5000]`.  ngOnit only pushes the val to firstVar one time right?

Comment: actually i see what is happening, but not sure how to fix it.  When you subscribe to an observable I've noticed that a console log will start with an empty array and then fill it with once new instance, and repeat until finished.  So out of the 3 items.  it was [ ]   then [1000] then [1000, 5000] then [1000, 5000, 1000]  so my ending array is populating all six integers into one array because of the push command I believe resulting in [1000, 1000, 5000, 1000, 5000, 1000].

Is there another option to use than push? I imagine something like set would work.