# How can I use the complete() when my asyn operation is completed?

Tags: angular, ionic2

My Code:

### .ts

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
  datas: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  // datas: FirebaseListObservable<Item[]>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public authData: AuthData, public af: AngularFire) { }
  ngOnInit() {

    this.datas = this.af.database.list('/datas');
    //console.log('datas'+JSON.stringify(this.datas));

  }

  loadData(refresher?: any) {
    callToProviderApi().subscribe(newData => {
      this.datas = newData;
    }, err => console.log(err),
      () =>if(refresher)
        refresher.complete());//call complete on subscribe complete
  }

  doRefresh(datas) {
    this.loadData(datas);
  }
```

### .html

```
<ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="doRefresh()">
        <ion-refresher-content>
          pullingIcon="arrow-dropdown"
        </ion-refresher-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let data of datas | async" class="pqr">
          <ion-thumbnail item-left>
            <img src="assets/image/{{data.imageName}}">
          </ion-thumbnail>
          {{data.Comp}}<br> 
          {{data.Demand}}<br>
          <p> {{data.Desig}}<br></p>
          {{data.Place}}<br>
           {{data.when}}<br>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
      </ion-refresher>
```

I have not understood the following points:

1. As dataset is asyn, Can't it be viewed in the console?
2. when I ran this code, the following error is displayed as runtime
   error: `Cannot read property 'complete' of undefined`.
3. When I navigate to the page where my content is shown, it does not
   show the content which is already present, as well as the refresher
   keeps on starting.

Note: Please let me know if more inputs and screenshots should be needed.

Comment: @sebaferreras can u help?

Answer (score 3):

> As dataset is asyn, Can't it be viewed in the console?

You are using an `async` pipe. You could log it by trying to print in the `ngOnChanges()` lifecyclehook.

> when I ran this code, the following error is displayed as runtime error: Cannot read property 'complete' of undefined.

You have made a minor error in your html call.You need to pass `$event` to your `doRefresh()`

```
<ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
        <ion-refresher-content>
          pullingIcon="arrow-dropdown"
        </ion-refresher-content>
</ion-refresher>
```

> When I navigate to the page where my content is shown, it does not show the content which is already present, as well as the refresher keeps on starting.

You need to use the ion-refresher api along with your data loading. I suggest you subscribe in the component for this instead of `async`.

```
 datas:any[];
loadData(refresher?:any){
  this.af.database.list('/datas').subscribe(newData=>{ //this is the asynchronous function you call which is setting your data..
     this.datas=newData;
  },err=>console.log(err),
  ()=>if(refresher)refresher.complete());//call complete on subscribe complete
}

doRefresh(datas){
  this.loadData(datas);
}
```

Also your `ion-list` should be outside the `ion-refresher` html block.
You could call `this.loadData();` from constructor.

Comment: Thank you suraj, i will try these out and get back to you.:) @suraj

Comment: Suraj, Point no.2 is done! I am implementing point no.3, but before implementing this, I want to understand this.
Can You tell me that why have we used here parameter refresher? what is its role?And secondly, what will callToProviderApi will do? @suraj

Comment: the $event is nothing but the refresher object you are expecting in the function..http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/refresher/Refresher/

Comment: callToProviderApi is nothing but the http call from which your data list is being set.. refresher parameter is just to complete loading once the list is loaded..if no refresher is sent(initial page load).. you dont have to call complete.if called through doRefresh call complete

Comment: where should I use this loadData function?

Comment: arent you loading in the component?

Comment: yes, Loading it in the component itself, But it is displaying that `cannot find name callToProviderApi();`

Comment: can you add your component code? what function are you calling to set data list ? that function.. I just set a name as I do not have your code..

Comment: it is showing error on`data:any[]` stating that `Duplicate identifier 'datas'.[ts] Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'datas' must be of type 'FirebaseListObservable<any[]>', but here has type 'any[]'.`

Comment: remove the old declaration..it just means debug your code a bit.

Comment: After removing the old one.It shows error on `this.datas` which is present in `ngOnInit()` stating `[ts]
Type 'FirebaseListObservable<any[]>' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
  Property 'length' is missing in type 'FirebaseListObservable<any[]>'.`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40787208/how-do-i-return-an-array-instead-of-a-firebaselistobservable